# Want to find week date based on given date and given week day

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a syntax in MS SQL like below : -

```
select DATEADD(WK, datediff(WK, **1**,'**2018-04-4**'), **1**);
```

here my approch is i am passing startdate i.e. (**'2018-04-4'**) and weekday i.e. **1** based on this formula it is giving me currect date based on week day

```
2018-04-03 00:00:00.000

if i am passing **6** result is 2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 
if i am passing **0** result is 2018-04-02 00:00:00.000  
if i am passing **1** result is 2018-04-03 00:00:00.000  
if i am passing **2** result is 2018-04-04 00:00:00.000 
if i am passing **3** result is 2018-04-05 00:00:00.000 
if i am passing **4** result is 2018-04-06 00:00:00.000 
if i am passing **5** result is 2018-04-07 00:00:00.000
```

Now my difficulty is i need to migrate this in MySQL, and it is not working there.

Please suggest any solution for getting result like above.

Comment: if you pass 3 it should be 5th of april. you have a typo

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

you can use date_Add and date_sub for this.

this gives you the first day of that week you are passing in,

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2018-04-04',INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2018-04-04') DAY);
```

combining that with date add, you can generate date with weekday

```
select date_add(date_sub('2018-04-04', interval weekday('2018-04-04') day), interval 3 day);
```

[image]

Comment: ,Here is one problem when i am running DATEADD(WK, datediff(wk, 6,'2018-04-4'), 6);  sql is giving me 2018-04-01 00:00:00.000  this date.
but in MySQL date_add(date_sub('2018-04-04', interval weekday('2018-04-04') day), interval 6 day) it is returning 2018-04-08 ? for 0,1 2,3,4,5 it is running correctly